# WordPress: Plugin Development overriding guide

Tags: wordpress

I have been developing plugins for WordPress. Most plugin I have developed with two three classes and not so huge like Buddypress, WooCommerce or etc.

I am planning to make two open source plugins to deliver some sort of complex system (detail can't share you at the moment but later during the development) where other developers can customize functions and system for them need same as Buddypress and WooCommerce.

As I check those plugins files and realize they have register them own action and filters which developers can modify as per them need. But my problem is unable to understand completely how I should write the plugin where other developer have flexibility to override plugin function as well as they can add them own.

I know it is difficult to give definite answer but I need some sort of start-up guide so I can go into right direction. Do I need to register my action and filters? If yes how to do? if not than how can I do?

Your hint will help me a lot... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can check [WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate), it should get you started on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to use wp-cli for generate plugin like so:

```
wp scaffold plugin my-plugin
```

Or using "WordPress Plugin Boilerplate" for more complex works: https://wpbp.github.io/wiki.html